# Detecting Apple Watch Using CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, apple-watch

I am discovering bluetooth devices using Core Bluetooth from my iPhone, but it does not pick up the Apple Watch. Is there something I'm missing? Here is the code I'm using below:

```
#pragma mark - CBCentralManagerDelegate

// method called whenever you have successfully connected to the BLE peripheral
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
}

// CBCentralManagerDelegate - This is called with the CBPeripheral class as its main input parameter. This contains most of the information there is to know about a BLE peripheral.
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{     NSLog(@"%@", [peripheral name]);
}


// method called whenever the device state changes.
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
switch ([central state])
{
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off");
        break;
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready");
        [[self bluetoothManager] scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
        break;
    case CBCentralManagerStateResetting:
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is resetting");
        break;
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized");
        break;
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnknown:
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");
        break;
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: I would be surprised if Core Blietooh could discover an Apple Watch.

Comment: 1) Are you checking for peripherals when the central state is PoweredOn, and 2) are you sure the bluetooth on the watch is turned on?

Comment: @josh951623 Yes, I am. The phone's bluetooth is PoweredOn and the bluetooth on the watch is on.

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't know about discovery, but you can see the watch when you call `retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices`.

Answer (score 0):

My Apple Watch shows up when I run the following code:

```
[self.centralManager retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180A"]]];
```

`180A` is the Device Information service.

Not sure which characteristics you can discover and subscribe to, if any, but you can definitely detect the watch's presence.

Comment: I'm going to test this out today. Thank you!

Comment: Is this doable from the App Delegate? I'm not seeing anything come up when I run this even after I confirm CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn.

Comment: That's weird, I get the watch straight after `centralManagerDidUpdateState` with the above code when `CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn`. If I turn the watch off it goes away. Maybe it's a bug, my watch _is_ in a funny state - I can't update it to 2.1.

Answer (score -1):

U do not use Core Bluetooth to connect to Apple Watch you use another framework called connectivity

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/using_watch_connectivity_to_communicate_between_your_apple_watch_app_and_iphone_app

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: You can look up the framework documentation for yourself I‘m not your teacher just here to help

Comment: The point is that you do not provide the kind of content StackOverflow is meant to contain. The downvote is not by me by the way, but it indicates that I am not the only one finding this answer lacking.

Comment: The question doesn't ask what framework should be used for communicating with an Apple Watch app from an iOS app, it asks how to detect an Apple Watch using Core Bluetooth. They _might_ want to use that detection for communicating with it, or they might want to use it to find all nearby Apple Watches, or any other number of use cases. Your answer is not only badly formed for StackOverflow, it doesn't even come close to answering the question.

Comment: legit try to improve it doesn't help the community I see